# Block spaces between characters cmd batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, spaces

I'm creating simple batch file with possibilities to allow user enter something and then display that user input on screen. Current situation is almost like this:

```
echo off
:first
cls
set userinput=
set /p userinput=Enter anything:
if not %userinput%==[%1]==[] goto valid
echo You entered nothing or spaces only
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
goto first
:valid
set userinput=%userinput: =%
echo You entered this text - %userinput%
pause >nul
```

This batch don't allow user to enter nothing or spaces only. But it allows to enter spaces and then text. Or text and then spaces. Or spaces-text-spaces. After batch crosses valid sector all these spaces is removed so user sees only real text.
Problem is that if user enters text then spaces and again text, batch just crashes, it closes. Is there any simple solution to block spaces between characters? Or block spaces at all?

Comment: The proper way to do an IF comparison of a string is to use QUOTES around your variables and strings.  `IF "%var%"=="blue" echo yes`

Comment: Is this really valid scripting? `if not %userinput%==[%1]==[]`

Comment: Yes, it works. `if not %userinput%=="%1"==""` works as well.

Comment: What do you believe to be the meaning of such an expression. Is it a logical `OR` or `AND`?

Comment: `%userinput%==[%1]==[]` is **not** valid. If `userinput` is empty, then the expression is evaluated as `[%1]==[]` intriguingly ignoring the leading `==` and the expression is evaluated as *true*, but since we have `if NOT` the `if` is *false*. If `userinput` is not empty (say `hello`) but it matches `%1` then the expression is evaluated as `hello==[hello]==[]`. `hello` is *not* equal to `[hello]==[]` so the expression is evaluated as *false* , but since we have `if NOT` the `if` is *true*. If you change `%1` to `jello` (or anything else)  then you *still* have the `if` being *true*

Answer (score 0):

Do the space removal, then check the input.

```
set /p userinput=Enter anything:
SET "userinput=%userinput: =%"
if not "%userinput%" EQU "" goto valid
echo You entered nothing or spaces only
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
goto first
:valid
echo You entered this text - %userinput%
pause >nul
```